# Validate a form for empty characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a form where I need to make all fields mandatory and I have written this code in Savebutton event for validation. Even after giving all values and I hit save it still shows me the alert message.

```
     if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDate.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTotalAmount.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMonthlyAmount.Text) || (ddlCode.Items.Count == 0) || (ddlCategory.Items.Count == 0) || (ddlDepartment.Items.Count == 0) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtRemarks.Text))
    {
        string message = "Please fill all the fields to save the data";
        string script = String.Format("alert('{0}');", message);
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "msgbox", script, true);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use validators? There is a `RequiredFieldValidator` which was made for this purpose.

Comment: what you do with ddlCategory items count? I think you should check ddl ddlCateogory.SelectedValue is null or empty or not? Also required field validator is also there you can that straight away

Comment: This part makes no sense, the user can only select an item in the dropdownlists, not add them? So it would never equal 0 right?

(ddlCode.Items.Count == 0) || (ddlCategory.Items.Count == 0) || (ddlDepartment.Items.Count == 0)

Comment: @ChristianMark - That would be fine.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - RequiredFieldValidator is working fine for save. Also I have a cancel button in the form and when I click on that it shows the alert for the fields to be entered. But actually it has to come out of the page when I click cancel. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score -2):

Using `RequiredVFieldValidator` Control is a better way.

Comment: Could you edit this to put into the context of the question? Thanks

Comment: As @JustinJDavies alludes to; this isn't really an answer at all, since it doesn't address the question. Nor does it explain at all.